# Got error in algorithm

Tags: algorithms

```
\RequirePackage{amsmath}

\documentclass[runningheads,a4paper]{llncs}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{algorithm}

\usepackage{algorithmicx}

\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\usepackage{titleps}

\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}
    \begin{algorithm}
        \caption{GroupAuth\_KeyExch(Group, 1, n)}
        \begin{algorithmic}
            Let’s assume Group = \{UE1, UE2, … , UEn\} and n represents the number of groups.
            Aim of this algorithm is to authenticate all the devices and establish a session key for the defined Group.
                    \{ 
            for i = 1 to n do
            \{
            Recive\_Msgi1 = null;
            Recive\_Msgi2 = null;
            Obtained\_Keyi = False;
            \}
        \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

got this error

Comment: Are you using `\usepackage{algorithmic}` or `\usepackage{algpseudocode}`?

Comment: As always please give us a compilable code, not only code snippet(s) ...

Comment: ya i used those packages and its a paper unable to give fully

Comment: @Prasad hence the term minimal example, for such a document. Make a smaller document with a representative preamble and document class, then post it here. Then others can copy and test your example as is without having to add anything or have to guess what is in your preamble.

Comment: @daleif i did my best but i dont know how to format it here as tex code

Comment: @Prasad, indent by at least 4 spaces. I just reedited it, marked the code and pressed Ctrl-k, that seems to indent stuff. I think you forgot to include the error message

Comment: The problem here is that the `algorithmic` environment has a very specific syntax, you can see it in the manual for `algpseudocode`, a syntax you do not use, thus the error.

Comment: @daleif i introduce /state and format for but i got lot of error so that i removed i got error in that end statement so that i gave like this.

Comment: Then please update the question to show what you have now. Trying to guess that you are doing, it not really helping

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for something like this. Yes, this syntax can be quite cumbersome. Sometimes it might be easier to write it in a verbatim like environment instead

```
    \begin{algorithmic}
      \State Let’s assume Group = \{UE1, UE2, … , UEn\} and n represents the number of groups.
      \State Aim of this algorithm is to authenticate all the devices and establish a session key for the defined Group.
      \For{i = 1 to n}
      \State \{
      \State Recive\_Msgi1 = null;
      \State Recive\_Msgi2 = null;
      \State Obtained\_Keyi = False;
      \State \}
      \EndFor
    \end{algorithmic}
```